# is it possible to have live gps tracking with Angular Google Maps?

Tags: angular, google-maps-api-3, ionic4

I am using an Angular Google Maps in my ionic application to try to make a tracking application. As it is, I can display current location and location between two markers but I am not sure how to track current location in real time like with uber.

```
            <agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom" [disableDefaultUI]="false"
              (mapReady)="mapReady(true, $event)" [styles]="style">
              <agm-marker *ngIf="driverReady" [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [markerDraggable]="false"
                [iconUrl]="markerUrl" (dragEnd)="markerDragEnd($event)"></agm-marker>
              <agm-direction *ngIf="meetStudent" [origin]="locationOrigin" [destination]="studentData.origin" [markerOptions]="markerOptions"
               [renderOptions]="renderOptions" >
              </agm-direction>
            </agm-map>
```

This is the AGM script displaying current location and direction between two markers. How can I track current location or do real time navigation between origin and destination with AGM?

Thanks

Comment: you have to use web sockets to get realtime changes so you can use it to show realtime updates

Comment: hi @HirasHaris, thanks for the response. Is there a resource you could direct me to that has some examples?

Comment: this might help you https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-lt

Comment: ionic blog to do geolocation things https://devdactic.com/ionic-location-tracker-map-track/

Comment: What are you using for you backend?  Couldn't you use firebase / firestore to update the lat and lon in realtime in the Ionic app when they change in the database.  No need to mess around with sockets.

Comment: I would suggest using Firebase, that has sockets build in when data changes, so immediately updates the client